# Downloading a file from a webpage on remote computers using a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, psexec

When I run this command locally on a remote machine it works:

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('<WebPath>', 'C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\file.exe')"
```

When I try the same command remotely using PsExec in a batch file:

```
(Set downloadFileCommand = powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%WebPath%', 'C$\Users\<user>\Desktop\file.exe')")

PsExec.exe \\<remote_machine> -u %username% -p %password% -s -d cmd /c %downloadFileCommand%
```

I am getting "cmd started on remote_machine with process ID #id_number."

However, nothing happened and the download wasn't executed. The suggestions here:
[Run PowerShell scripts on remote PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786185/run-powershell-scripts-on-remote-pc)

didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

***Edit:***

I managed to download the file through the command line (in cmd) using this command:

```
PsExec.exe \\<remote_machine> -u <username> -p <password> -d powershell -Command (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('<url address','C:\file.exe')
```

But it doesn't work when I try this in a batch file:

```
(Set DownloadInstaller = "powershell -Command (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('<url address','C:\file.exe')")

PsExec.exe \\<remote_machine> -u %username% -p %password% -h -d cmd /c %DownloadInstaller%
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using psexec over Invoke-Command?

Comment: Just was familiar with it... I'll try Invoke-Command.

Comment: @Persistent13 Some environments block RPC and/or WinRM, leaving PsExec as the only other option.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: On my computer it's 4.0. On the remote computer it's 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked - all in one line. I have a loop variable, a remote computer (%%a). I assumed that when I use PsExec, C:\ ... \file.exe "thinks" of C:\ locally in the remote computer, but that probably wasn't the case.

I had to write it all in one line, since the path in DownloadFile (The location I want to download the file to) is locally in the remote computer (which is a loop variable):

```
PsExec.exe \\%%a -u %username% -p %password% -h -d cmd /c powershell.exe -Command "&{ (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%url%','\\%%a\C$\Users\<username>\Desktop\%file%')}")
```